# Non-Isomorphic groups of order 20

Tags: group-theory

How many and which distinct groups of order 20 that are not isomorphic?  Why are they not isomorphic?  I have the $Z_{20}, Z_2+Z_{10}, D_{10}$.

There are more than 4.  I don't know the limit.

Comment: There are more than 4.

Comment: There are exactly $5$ non-isomorphic groups of order $20$. If you are aware of semi-direct products, look at SnowAngel6147's answer in the link Dan provided. If you know about presentations, the remaining two can also be found [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_affine_group:GA%281,5%29) and [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group:Dic20).